# What should happen to someone who _____ convicted of murder?

Tags: questions

> What should happen to someone who _____ convicted of murder?

The options are

> - has
> - get
> - gets

I translated it but the three options has sense in Spanish.

Which word is correct in this sentence and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer from those options would be "gets", although personally I would use either "has been" or "is".

Answer (score 1):

Your translations probably won't help, because the differences are grammatical rather than semantic.

You need the verb phrase to be passive (it is the court of law which *convicts* the accused), so the auxiliary must be *be* or (more informally) *get*.

The auxiliary *get* is not a modal (eg *can*, *may*, *should*), so it must agree with the subject. The subject is presumably singular, so *gets* is the choice that fits.

Incidentally, *traduce* in your title is a false friend: the word you want is *translate*. *Traduce* means "to speak maliciously and falsely of; slander; defame: eg *to traduce someone's character*." (dictionary.com)